# Show both existing & non-existing ID's comparing two tables in <select>

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table 'team' of employees names & their IDs

```
ID | Employee_Name
------------------
1    John
2    Joe
3    Jack
4    Jill
```

Im saving projects allocated for these employees in an array in the 'projects' table as 'Employee_IDS'

```
ID | Project_Name | Employee_IDS
--------------------------------
1    Abc Project    1,3,4
2    Dfg Project    2,4
```

-

I want to display the list of employees that has been assigned to a specific
project and and those who are not.

The php variable that has the array is $ppemployees.

```
<select name="pemployees[]" id="pemployees" multiple>                                                                
  <?php
    $myArray1 = explode(',', $ppemployees);
    foreach($myArray1 as $my_Array1)
    {
      $sqlget5 = "SELECT * FROM team WHERE id=\"$my_Array1\";";
      $resget5 = mysql_query($sqlget5);
      if(mysql_num_rows($resget5) == 0)
      {
        ?>                                                            
          <option value="<?php echo $row5['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row5['FirstName']; ?></option>
        <?php
      }
      else
      {
        while($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($resget5))
        {
          ?>                                                            
            <option value="<?php echo $row5['id']; ?>" selected><?php echo $row5['FirstName']; ?></option>
          <?php
        }
      }
    }                                                                
  ?>
```

Currently im getting only the existing values, i want to show the non existing also.

Comment: you are using any checkboxes for displaying the employees which are assigned in projects.. how your display view should be...??

Comment: @Sona Im using multi-select

Comment: how you are highliting the people which are in the projects at the same time how you are showing the employyees which are not in the project??

Comment: I just want to get id's that are matching as <option selected>Matching Value</option> and not matching as <option>Non-Matching Value</option>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query which uses `FIND_IN_SET()` to join the two tables:

```
SELECT t2.Project_Name,
       t1.Employee_Name,
       CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(t1.ID, t2.Employee_IDS) > 0
            THEN 'Assigned'
            ELSE 'Unassigned' END AS status
FROM team t1
INNER JOIN projects t2
ORDER BY t2.Project_Name, t1.Employee_Name
```

Note that we actually use a cross join here, which in MySQL can be expressed using an `INNER JOIN` with no `ON` condition.  The reason for the cross join is that we want to match up every employee with every project, regardless of any condition.  Then, we use a `CASE` expression to determine whether or not an employee be assigned to a particular project.

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I just want to get id's that are matching as <option selected>Matching Value</option> and not matching in as <option>Non-Matching Value</option>